# Как отследить просмотр tooltip на разных устройствах?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Всем привет. Хочу отследить просмотр tooltip bootstrap пользователем. В чем проблема: тултипы показываются на мобильниках и на ПК по разным событиям. ПК - наведение, мобильные устройства - клик. Если например навесить событие клик - все понятно, сработает при нажатии, но основная проблема с дескстоп версией, если повесить событие маусмув, то оно сработает всегда, даже если курсор при скролле проходил через элемент, в таком случае фактически будет происходить событие но пользователь не прочитал подсказку…

Как можно отследить событие показа .tooltip-inner ? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, внутри обработчика поставить setTimeout в котором прописать логику фиксации просмотра тултипа. Если пользак случайно задел, то сразу же сработает mouseleave и можно через cleareTimeout остановить таймер

Comment: Ой, спасибо за подсказку, я уже сделал с учетом вашего ответа, но пока не могу добраться до пк, как доберусь выложу свой вариант.

Comment: Ой какой плохой совет... вы этим setTimeout заставляете пользователей греть процессоры устройств в независимости, попадет пользователь туда или нет тем самым садите батарею их устройств.А потом нехватка электричества у человечества, глобальное потепление, таяние ледников ... потому-что подвязались на событие за которое "якоби" ни кто не платит. Не надо так делать. Почитайте про тротлинг в js ... Ваша задача решаеться точно так же как проблема с показом специфектов при скроллинге.

Answer (score 0):

Добрался до пк, выкладываю свой вариант решения своего же вопроса, с учетом ранее полученных ответов и документации bootstrap. В общем я сделал так:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 let start;
$('#tooltip_temp').on('show.bs.tooltip', function () { 
 start = setTimeout(() => { 
alert('Смотрели подсказку')
 }, 5000) 
 }) 
 $('#tooltip_temp').on('hide.bs.tooltip', function () { 
 clearTimeout(start); 
 }) 
})
```

Конечно, наверняка есть более локаничное представление кода, более красивое и ёмкое, буду рад если оптимизируете, а так вот этот код сработал.